# Laravel eloquent how to get the minimum value that is not NULL?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is the code in my `Product` model to get the minimum price value (one product can have multiple price)

```
public function getLowestAttribute ()
{
    return $this->prices->min('price');
}
```

But it will return `NULL` rather than the smallest integer if there is a `NULL`.

Basically I want to achieve this:

`[1, NULL, 2]` returns `1`

`[1, NULL, 0]` returns `0`

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: And what if the values are `NULL` only, something like as `[NULL, NULL]`

Comment: @Uchiha it's impossible in my case. Because the product needs to have at least one non-null price before it can be added into the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found `filter`, and it works now.

```
public function getLowestAttribute ()
{
    $prices = $this->prices->filter(function ($item) {
        return !is_null($item->price);
    });

    return $prices->min('price');
}
```

Comment: FWIW, as of Laravel 5.1, it is possible to not provide a callback to the filter function - this will remove any items that [equal `false`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried maybe

```
public function getLowestAttribute ()
{
    return $this->prices->where('price','>=',0)->min('price');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A fix to the KuKeC answer would be

```
public function getLowestAttribute()
{
    return $this->prices->where('price', '!==', null)->min('price');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous 2 solutions provided did not work for me in Laravel 6.2 neither I want filter unless I have to

I used per documentation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses

```
… ->whereNotNull('price')-> …
```

Although in my specific situation I needed NULLs so I actually used

```
… ->whereNull('price')-> …
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer, It works for me

```
public function getLowestAttribute ()
{
    return $this->prices->whereNotNull('price')->min('price');
}
```